# Getting the results of a method to be placed into another .m file

Tags: objective-c, methods, int

This may sound easy, but please, I am a newbie.  I have a simple program that I need help resolving this issue.  I would like to get the results in a method and place it into another .m file.  Here is what I have:

CheckRecognizer .m
....

```
-(int)good {

    if (fieldGoal == NO && fieldGoalPosition == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    else if (fieldGoal == YES && fieldGoalPosition == 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    else if (fieldGoal == NO && fieldGoalPosition == 2) {
        return 2;
    }

...        
}
```

Then I have this in my ViewController .m:

```
fieldGoal1 = [CheckRecognizer good];
```

I have #import "CheckRecognizer.h" in my file, but it won't recognize the 'good' method.  Can you please help?  I have tried everything, like naming a variable to be accessed in the other .m file with no success.  Thank you.

Comment: First of all, your method is returning values based on some existing values. Are they instance variables or static variables? If they are instance variables, simple `alloc-init-good` will give you 0 as `NO` and `0` will be default values of `fieldGoal` and `fieldGoalPosition` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared your method as an instance method, but called it as a class method. You need to instantiate an instance:

```
CheckRecognizer *recognizer = [CheckRecognizer alloc] init];
```

And then use it:

```
int result = [recognizer good];
```

You should also come up with a better method name than "good."

Answer (score 2):

either make good a class method, 
+(int) good { ... }

or call good on instance of CheckRecognizer ,
[[[CheckRecognizer alloc] init] good];

I strongly suggest you to go through http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html.

Answer (score 0):

fieldGoal1 = [[[CheckRecognizer alloc]init]autorelease]good];

Now if this is the correct way of doing stuff, that is an entirely different question ;)